# How to design a sampling scheme for rare events

Tags: sampling, rare-events

In sampling design for ecology we often come across sampling rare events. For instance estimating the total number of animals in a region. To achieve minimum logistic cost, we apply systematic sampling with large sized grids, where each gird represents a certain sized area. The total is then estimated by the mean density (number/area per grid) multiplied by the total area of the region. This often results in overestimation the total when the sampling grid hit a cluster of animals (high peak). On the other hand, the location of such clusters is difficult to determine prior to sampling design and it may vary.

Does anyone have any suggestions or good idea about how to handle this kind of sampling design?

The ultimate goal is to increase precision of the estimate. However, in practice some theoretically sound solutions might be logistically too expensive, and we are also interested in more practical solutions, such as just to optimize the sampling grid. So both theoretical and practical solutions are welcome.

Comment: Is your focus only on the design of the sampling grid or do you really want to optimize the final output (the estimated number of animals)? In the later case there are also suggestions to make about how to use the samples you have.

Comment: @Erik, we would like to focus on the precision of final estimated total. However, the final practical logistic factor might limit us to come to a compromised solution of optimizing the grid. Both theoretical and practical suggestions are welcome to me.

Comment: Do you have any prior knowledge about cluster sizes, mean densities? Anything about the spatial distribution of the population?

Comment: @Aksakal, It is difficult to get such information even given a long time series sampling survey. The cluster moves, and the sampling grid is too large to construct a density distribution,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not my area of expertise, so I expect a better answer to be along.

#### Designing the grid

Let us say you sample 1% of the area of each grid.

The number of animals you find in that 1% is probably [Poisson distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) since it is a count and your estimate for the final number of animals in the specific area of the grid would one hundred times the observed number, correct?

The variance of the Poisson distribution is the same as the mean. This means that your main error comes from those areas where there are relatively many animals.

This suggests that if you have an a priori estimate of the density you should make the grid finer in places where you expect many animals. Having the same product of density and size in each area of the grid should yield good results.

Don't go this post-hoc by subdiving the grid because you observed many animals there, this will lead to a bias because it corrects over-estimates but not under-estimates.

#### Change the estimation method

There is also a model-based option, similar to what is usually done in field trials. Fit a mixed Poisson regression model to the data using a spatial covariance structure. This will effectively smooth the number of animals you observed in each area of the grid, so that individual over- and underestimatations are corrected.

This [paper](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=poisson+regression+model+spatial) by Mohebbi, Wolfe and Forbes uses a similar method for disease mapping:

Mohebbi, M., Wolfe, R., & Jolley, D. (2011). A poisson regression approach for modelling spatial autocorrelation between geographically referenced observations. BMC medical research methodology, 11(1), 133.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I find them very useful. Do you think mixed Poisson regression model using a spatial covariance structure is similar to applying a GAM (or GAMM) model with a smoother to the grid coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

If the animals tend to cluster in any way, then the standard method for estimating abundance is adaptive sampling. The basic idea: once a target animal is found,  a search of the neighboring areas is launched. See this accessible exposition: http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php. A recent text is George A. F. Seber, M. Mohammad Salehi (2013), Adaptive Sampling Designs: Inference for Sparse and Clustered Populations (Springer Briefs in Statistics)